# htaccess: redirecting traffic to maintenance page removes images from maintenance page

Tags: html, apache, .htaccess

When I put my website in maintenance mode, I redirect all traffic to a `notice.html` webpage, except for traffic coming from my IP address (e.g. `111.111.111.111` below), by including the following lines in my `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^111\.111\.111\.111
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/notice\.html$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.mydomain.com/notice.html [R=307,L]
```

This seems to work well except for one issue -- if I include an image in the `notice.html` HTML code, such as

```
<img src="/path/to/myimage.png">
```

then this image file is no longer displayed (for IP addresses other than 111.111.111.111). If I comment out the above lines in my `.htaccess` file, then the image loads.

Any idea how I can whitelist the image file while I'm redirecting?

Comment: Of course the image is no longer displayed, because the request for it gets rewritten to notice.html as well – and since that’s not an actual image, but an HTML document, the browser will not display an image. But since you already seem to know how to add an exception to your rewriting for that notice.html – we keeps you from adding another one for that particular image?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The image is no longer displayed, because the request for it gets rewritten to `notice.html` as well – and since that’s not an actual image, but an HTML document, the browser will not display an image.

But since you already seem to know how to add an exception to your rewriting for that `notice.html`, you should just add another one for that particular image, so that it can be served even when your site is in maintenance mode.

Comment: Thanks @CBroe, What got it working was adding to htaccess: `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/path/to/myimage\.png$`